# how to get genre in list

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

i m trying to get genre in list from below code.in the same way i got songs and albums bu t not getting genres.when app runs it nothing shows any error but shows blank activity.i have no idea what is wrong in this code.please give me some solution.let me know if you want another details.
genreActivity

```
public class BlankFragment3 extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<genreInfo> genreList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView2;
    private genreAdapter genreAdapter1;
    String id;
    Cursor cursor;
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


    public BlankFragment3() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.genrere, container, false);
        recyclerView2 = rootView. findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);
        genreAdapter1 = new genreAdapter(genreList, getActivity());
        recyclerView2.setAdapter(genreAdapter1);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView2.getContext(),
                linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView2.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        getGenreList();
        return rootView;
    }
    public void getGenreList() {
        String[] proj1 = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID
        };
        ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
        cursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj1, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME);
                String genre = cursor.getString(index);
                index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID);
                long genreId = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(index));
                Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri("external", genreId);
                Cursor tempCursor = cr.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                if (tempCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    while (tempCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        index = tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                        String title = tempCursor.getString(index);
                        index = tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST);
                        String artist = tempCursor.getString(index);
                        index = tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM);
                        String album = tempCursor.getString(index);
                        genreInfo g = new genreInfo(artist, title, album, genre);
                        genreList.add(g);
                    }
                    tempCursor.close();
                }

            }

        }

    }





    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
genreAdapter

public class genreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<genreAdapter.GenreHolder> {
    ArrayList<genreInfo> genreList=new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver;
    byte[] art;

    public genreAdapter(ArrayList<genreInfo> genreList, Context context) {
        this.genreList = genreList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public genreAdapter.GenreHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View myView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.genre,parent,false);
        return new GenreHolder(myView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GenreHolder holder, int position) {
        final genreInfo a = genreList.get(position);
        holder.album.setText(genreList.get(position).getAlbum());
        holder.title.setText(genreList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.artist.setText(genreList.get(position).getArtist());
       /*
     holder.artist.setText(genreList.get(position).getdName());
     holder.album_art.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(String.valueOf(albumList.get(position).getAlbumImg())));
     */
       /* metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaRetriver.setDataSource(String.valueOf(genreList.get(position).getID()));
        try {
            art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
            Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art,0,art.length);
            holder.album_art.setImageBitmap(songImage);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            holder.album_art.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        }*/
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return genreList.size();
    }

    public class GenreHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView album;
        public TextView artist;
        public TextView title;
      //  public ImageView album_art;
        public GenreHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
          //  album_art = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumArt);
            artist = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.artistName);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleName);
            album = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.songName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are filling your `ArrayList` after creating adapter but at that time `ArrayList` is empty,

call `getGenreList();` before creating adapter.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.genrere, container, false);
        recyclerView2 = rootView. findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);
        getGenreList();
        genreAdapter1 = new genreAdapter(genreList, getActivity());
        recyclerView2.setAdapter(genreAdapter1);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView2.getContext(),
                linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView2.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

        return rootView;
    }
```